# Monitor system resources and save a log

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory-usage, monitoring

I got a server which works fine for a while and then suddenly eats up all the memory and then hangs.

I need to be able to monitor it and thought that I could use the Resource Monitor. but I haven't found a way to make it log everything into a log file? I can't log into the server when it have consumed all memory (have to reboot it first), thus a log file is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Windows Performance Monitor. You can create a Data Collector Set that logs the metrics you want to a log file.